Weird android recovery/fastboot countdown timer
I have a device running Android 10. The bootloader is unlocked. I was able to flash TWRP but there's something strange happening. I guess it's because the manufacturer has enabled boot time USB stick firmware updates. So, they have put a countdown timer during the boot time. Normally, the device starts, periodically it gets into "update mode" where it waits for 10 seconds for a USB stick with an updated firmware and if not found it boots into the Android OS normally.
My issue is, the same happens when I boot into bootloader(fastboot or fastbootd) OR TWRP!
I can see the TWRP screen I can navigate normally through the menus but suddenly at 10 seconds the device auto reboots itself into the OS, no matter what I was doing in TWRP at the time!
My question is, where is this triggered from and how can I stop it? Where a countdown timer during boot time is triggered from?
I have no clue where to look for and for what.
Thank you!
